# Django GraphQL JWT: tokenAuth mutation returns "str object has no attribute decode"

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django, django-graphql-jwt

Currently I'm running a basic example of django-graphqljwt from the documentation page. https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

```
import graphene
import graphql_jwt


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
    refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(mutation=Mutation)
```

However if I run the `tokenAuth` mutation it throws me the below error in the `GraphiQL` interface. **Note** that if I enter incorrect credentials it throws an "`Please enter valid credentials`" instead of the below.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "'str' object has no attribute 'decode'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "tokenAuth"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "tokenAuth": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found this as an open issue on github for the `django-graphql-jwt` package and was able to resolve it by resorting to the `1.7.0` version of `PyJWT`. Currently installed was version `2.0`

https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/issues/241

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the `django-graphql-jwt==0.2.1` without this problem. Apparently, the problem is related to the new version of `django-graphql-jwt` which is `0.3.0` by now. Or, as you mentioned, you could bound the `PyJWT` to `1.7.0`.

The solution is using these bounded packages in your `requirements.txt` file as follows:

```
django-graphql-jwt==0.3.0
PyJWT==1.7.0
```

Or

```
django-graphql-jwt==0.2.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue, this was apparently because `PyJWT==2.3.0` was not compatible with `django-graphql-jwt` as Dipanshu mentioned in his answer, It worked after downgrading `PyJWT==2.3.0` to `PyJWT==1.7.0`.

Check if the PyJWT package's version in your virtual environment is greater than 2.0.0 using the below pip command

```
pip show PyJWT
```

If it is greater than 2.0.0, use the below pip command to downgrade the package in your virtual environment

```
pip install --upgrade PyJWT==1.7.0
```