# Using @login_required for queries/mutations in django-graphql-jwt leads to graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError

Tags: python, django, graphql, jwt, graphene-django

I'm a begginer with GraphQL and started developing a small app using Django and decided to use django-graphql-jwt for authentication.

I can use the getTokenAuth, VerifyToken and RefreshToken with no problem. But when I try to use a query with decorator @login_required, all I get is a "GraphQLLocatedError: You do not have permission to perform this action" response. But, somehow, the unit tests are working nicely.

My code:

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

GRAPHENE = {
    "SCHEMA": "myproject.graphql.api.schema",
    "MIDDLWARE": [
        "graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware",
    ],
}

GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_ALLOW_ARGUMENT": True,
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
    "JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(days=7),
    "JWT_AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "Authorization",
    "JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX": "Bearer",
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
]
```

queries.py

```
from graphene import String, ObjectType
from graphql_jwt.decorators import login_required

class HelloQuery(ObjectType):
    hello = String(name=String(default_value="stranger"))

    @login_required
    def resolve_hello(self, info, name):
        return f"Hello {name}!"
```

tests.py

```
from graphql_jwt.testcases import JSONWebTokenTestCase
from users.factories import UserFactory

class QueryTest(JSONWebTokenTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory()
        self.client.authenticate(self.user)
        super().setUp()

    def test_00_hello(self):
        """
        This test evaluates the HelloQuery
        """

        query = """
            query hello {
                hola: hello(name: "tester")
            }
        """
        result = self.client.execute(query)
        self.assertIsNone(result.errors)
        self.assertEqual("Hello tester!", result.data["hola"])
```

Request info

```
POST http://localhost:8000/graphql
200
34 ms
Network
Request Headers
X-CSRFToken: 7ZZrDHmpkly1FHexdLASComfiqCo81iaHOHJuywRabRHsdIDgKbBXK3ex687G7Xt
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImpvY2hvIiwiZXhwIjoxNjE0MjczNTcxLCJvcmlnSWF0IjoxNjE0MjczMjY0fQ.C6yDzim5jliu6yIMDJ70Xl3WPP69HpYTR0VSGmy0brc
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 80a0c7fe-34c1-4972-8c3f-9342e9d047e1
Host: localhost:8000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 63
Cookie: JWT=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImpvY2hvIiwiZXhwIjoxNjE0MjczNTcxLCJvcmlnSWF0IjoxNjE0MjczMjY0fQ.C6yDzim5jliu6yIMDJ70Xl3WPP69HpYTR0VSGmy0brc; csrftoken=7ZZrDHmpkly1FHexdLASComfiqCo81iaHOHJuywRabRHsdIDgKbBXK3ex687G7Xt
Request Body
query: "query hello {
    hola: hello(name: "tester")
}"
variables: ""
Response Headers
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 17:14:37 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.9.1
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 149
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=7ZZrDHmpkly1FHexdLASComfiqCo81iaHOHJuywRabRHsdIDgKbBXK3ex687G7Xt; expires=Thu, 24 Feb 2022 17:14:37 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Response Body
{"errors":[{"message":"You do not have permission to perform this action","locations":[{"line":2,"column":5}],"path":["hola"]}],"data":{"hola":null}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your `queries.py` code snippet as follows:

```py
from graphene import String, ObjectType

class HelloQuery(ObjectType):
    hello = String(name=String(default_value="stranger"))

    def resolve_hello(self, info, name):
        user = info.context.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return f"Hello {name}!"
        return None
```

Note that the latest `graphene` version (`v0.3.0`) has an unresolved problem in which you have to add `PyJWT==1.7.0` package into your `requirements.txt` to resolve that – (The [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65704023/3702377))